# IObservable of keys pressed

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

So I can experiment with Reactive Extensions, I'd like to create an IObservable of keys pressed by the user. How can I do this?

This is for a C# console application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get an observable sequence of read keys:

```
        IObservable<System.ConsoleKeyInfo> keys =
            Observable
                .Defer(() =>
                    Observable
                        .Start(() =>
                            Console.ReadKey()))
                .Repeat();
```

I tested this and it worked like a treat.

Comment: If I subscribe two handlers to this, only one of them will handle each event (at random, for each event). This isn't what I expected, I expected both handlers to each receive every event

Comment: `keys.Subscribe(x => Console.Write("1", x.Key));keys.Subscribe(x => Console.Write("0", x.Key));Thread.Sleep(-1);` then type 'abc' I see "a1b1c0" rather than "a1a0b1b0c0c1"

Comment: @MattHickford - That's what you should expect to see - something like "a1b1c0". With two subscriptions you create two independent calls to `ReadKey()` on different threads and both wont read each key press. It is a case of one or the other. You could have equally got "a1b0c1" or any other combination.

Comment: @MattHickford - You need to publish the observable to have subscriptions share the key presses.

Comment: @Enigmativity @MattHickford What about cancellation? I've added an answer which allows for cancellation of the prompt by `Dispose`

Comment: Enigmativity, is this right to share keys? `var keys = Observable.Defer(() =>
                Observable.Start(
                    () =>Console.ReadKey()))
            .Repeat()
            .Publish();
keys.Connect();`

Comment: Is this really the easiest way to do this?

Comment: @Carbon you have an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

The blocking versions of ReadKey() have a problem, in that if you dispose the subscription, it still prompts you to press a key.

If you want to have a clean unsubscription, i.e, be able to cancel the prompt, it's (unfortunately) necessary to go with a polling approach.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
          .Where(_ => Console.KeyAvailable)
          .Select(_ => (char)Console.ReadKey(false).Key)
```

You can now do cool things like `Amb` this stream with `Observable.Timer` to set up a timeout for keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way how to read key presses asynchronously, so I think you have to use the synchronous [`Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey) on a separate thread, along with [`Subject<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Something like:

```
IObservable<ConsoleKeyInfo> ObserveKeysUntilEscape()
{
    var keys = new Subject<ConsoleKeyInfo>();

    Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey();
                keys.OnNext(key);
            } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
            keys.OnCompleted();
        });

    return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the method from @svick is to have the `ReadKey` loop as an `Enumerable`, and convert to an `Observable`. This puts it in the background.

```
    static IEnumerable<ConsoleKeyInfo> KeyPresses()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            yield return key;
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
```

We can generate the observables on the thread pool:

```
        var keys = KeyPresses().ToObservable(System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.ThreadPool);
        keys.Subscribe(key => Console.WriteLine("Pressed: {0}", key.Key));
```

And wait on the main thread for the `Escape` key:

```
        keys.Where(key => key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape).First();
```