# Reactive program doesn't terminate after wait

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I expected the program below to echo any key presses until you hit `z`, but it doesn't terminate when you hit `z`, and only echos every other keypress. What have I done wrong?

```
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

public class Printer : IObserver<char>
{ 
    public void OnNext(char x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    public void OnError(Exception x)
    {

    }
    public void OnCompleted()
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static IObservable<char> keys = Observable.Defer(() =>Observable.Start(() =>Console.ReadKey().KeyChar)).Repeat(); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675451/iobservable-of-keys-pressed
    public static int Main()
    {
        IObserver<char> x = new Printer();
        keys.Subscribe(x);
        keys.Where(b => b == 'z').Wait();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating multiple subscriptions. If you want to share the key presses you need to publish the observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so two issues, both separate:

1. What you have here is a [cold observable](https://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html). 
   It's only when you start observing it that it produces values.
   Conversely, each time you subscribe to it, it represents a new stream - similar to how `IEnumerable` evaluates every time you try to take items. You can see this clearly if you put a breakpoint inside the `Observable.Defer`.

   You can have those two streams [share just one subscription to the source](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#connectable), i.e, the key-press observable. So we convert the cold observable into a hot one.
2. The `Wait` method is:

   > Waits for the observable sequence to **complete** and returns the last element of
   >   the sequence. If the sequence terminates with an OnError notification, the exception
   >   is thrown.

   So it's going to wait till the sequence completes, i.e., an `OnCompleted` has been called down the observable chain. So, we use `TakeUntil` so that the sequence completes only when a condition is met (pressing 'z').

   ```
       public static int Main()
       {
           var keys_stream = keys.Publish().RefCount(); // share

           IObserver<char> x = new Printer();
           keys_stream.Subscribe(x);
           keys_stream.TakeUntil(b => b == 'z').Wait(); //wait until z
           return 0;
       }
   ```